# Doubt about friction force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction

It's probably a very basic question, but I am somewhat stuck with it: Let's consider some object at rest and some force acting on it, trying to put it to motion. Then, there will be a static friction force which stays equal to the applied force, until some critical force $\mu_s F_N$ is reached. At this point the object starts moving and feels a kinetic (or sliding) friction force which is approximately constant and given by $\mu_k F_N$, where $\mu_k<\mu_s$. So the friction force looks like in the following graph: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict2.html

However, there is also a rolling friction force, which is given by $\mu_r F_N$ with $\mu_r<\mu_k$. Again, if I try to put an object into motion, it will first be subject to a static friction force until some critical force is reached, the object starts rolling and the friction force drops to a lower value $\mu_r F_N$.

*Now, the question is, is the critical force at which the object starts to move dependent on whether sliding or rolling will ensue? If it is, is the critical force required for initiating a rolling movement equal to zero? If not, how can it be calculated?*

Intuitively, it is easier to make things roll than make them slide, so not only are the friction forces different when the object is already moving, but also the critical force required to make them start moving is different (lower for rolling than for sliding).

But on the other hand, the static friction coefficient is said to be only dependent on the pair of materials in question (say, steel on steel or rubber on asphalt) and on nothing else.

I understand that there is most probably some very complex physics going on and there are better models than $F_{fr} = \mu F_N$ for the friction force, but I still wonder, if this question can be answered using this simple model?

Comment: The link (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict2.html) you shared in your question has your answer in the last box which is about 'rolling friction'. Rolling friction is not a 'surface friction' but instead is defined to account for energy losses which take place during rolling of real objects. It is not a surface phenomenon like the static friction.

Comment: So, what does this imply regarding the critical force required to make an object start moving?

Comment: Since both rolling friction and (static and kinetic) friction have different origins, critical force dependents on whether sliding or rolling ensues. Critical force for rolling is far less than that for normal friction.

Comment: In the _ideal_ of rolling motion, there is never any sliding contact between the ball and the surface. The velocity of the _surface_ of the ball at the exact point of contact always is zero. Since there's no sliding contact, that means, static friction is never "broken."

Comment: @SolomonSlow So, static friction is zero and the graph would be just a horizontal line in this ideal case?

Comment: Static friction isn't necessarily zero. If something is pushing the ball—accelerating it—then there will be non-zero static friction between the ball and the surface as it rolls. The offset between the point where static friction is applied and the point where the "push" is applied is what will provide the angular acceleration that causes the ball to start rolling.

Comment: @Photon After considerable thought, I think I may have the answer. I am formulating it and hope to post it soon as possible as a new answer. Bob

Comment: @Photon See my new answer.

Answer (score 6):

> Now, the question is, is the critical force at which the object starts
> to move dependent on whether sliding or rolling will ensue?

What you call "rolling friction" is more properly referred to as "rolling resistance". Unlike kinetic friction, which is energy loss due to the relative motion (slipping/sliding) between surfaces, rolling resistance is related to energy loss due to inelastic behavior of the materials of the contacting surfaces (rolling object plus surface) when the materials are  compressed and uncompressed while in contact with one another. The compression force acting opposite the direction of motion is greater than the decompression force acting in the direction of motion, for a net force opposing motion.

The coefficient of rolling resistance is generally much smaller than the coefficient of kinetic friction which, in turn, is generally somewhat less than the coefficient of static friction. See the Wikipedia article on Rolling Resistance.

That said, which type of "friction" is applicable depends on what type of "moving" is involved. There is "moving" without rotation (translational motion), "moving" without sliding (rotational motion), or a combination of the two (rotation with slipping).

If the object is not capable of rolling, for example, a block, then "move" means relative motion between the object and the surface below, i.e., strictly translational motion. In that case, the critical force is the maximum possible static friction, or $\mu_{s}N$, as discussed in the Hyperphysics link. In this case rolling resistance does not apply.

If the object is capable of rolling (i.e.,a  circular object), then you need to distinguish between the initiation of rolling and the maintaining of rolling.

To initiate rolling without slipping requires a static friction force. That force will match the pushing or pulling force on the object, or the force the object exerts on the surface due to torque applied to the object, up until the maximum possible static friction force is reached when slipping occurs and friction becomes kinetic. If the applied force or torque does not result in the maximum static friction being exceeded, then pure rolling begins almost instantaneously. Opposing the pure rolling is rolling resistance. But since the rolling resistance force is so much less than the static friction force during acceleration, the net force is essentially the static friction force. If the maximum static friction force is exceeded, slipping occurs and friction opposing motion becomes kinetic. However, again rolling resistance is much less than kinetic friction so the net force opposing motion is essentially the kinetic friction force.

So when does rolling resistance play an important role? When there is pure rolling with no external forces acting in the direction of motion, then rolling resistance is one of the primary reasons a rolling object will slow down. The others are air resistance, bearing friction, etc. An example is the slowing of a bicycle or car that is coasting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! "If the applied force or torque does not result in the maximum static friction being exceeded, then pure rolling begins almost instantaneously." But there is still some critical force required, which needs to be exceeded to make the object start rolling, right? Think of trying to pull a train, for example. But it looks like this critical force is lower than what is given by $\mu_s F_N$, right? Is there some expression for this "critical rolling force" as well?

Comment: @Photon instead of a person pulling a train how about we consider the more realistic example of a person pulling a cart?

Comment: @Photon I’m going to update my answer using the example of a man pushing a car. Please stand by

Comment: Sure, a car is also perfectly fine, I just wanted to use some extreme example which demonstrates that even when rolling, the object won't start accelerating unless a sufficiently high force is applied.

Comment: @Photon Take the example of a man attempting to push a car in neutral on a horizontal dry asphalt road surface. Its seems to me that  the minimum force he would need to apply  to get it moving would be the rolling resistance force, but I’m not sure exactly how to quantify that force since rolling resistance is normally specified as the force opposing motion while rolling, as opposed to the force resisting the initiation of rolling.

Comment: The description of rolling resistance from  Wikipedia, which is typical of other descriptions, is “ (Rolling resistance) is the force resisting the motion when a body (such as a ball, tire, or wheel) rolls on a surface”.  But to me, it seems rolling resistance must also play a role in resisting the initiation of rolling. For example, I would think it would be harder to start moving a car with under inflated tires which increases rolling resistance.

Comment: Once the car starts rolling then, at low speeds achievable by a man (where air drag is not a factor), the forces opposing motion  include the static friction force responsible for causing the tires to rotate (overcoming their rotational moment of inertia) and the rolling resistance force.  Regarding the static friction force, to quote from one site: “ all that (static) force has to do is to provide sufficient torque to give the (non -drive) wheels the correct angular acceleration”.

Comment: It is generally considered negligible compared to the traction force needed to cause the acceleration of the entire vehicle as well as the rolling resistance force.

Comment: According to one site “ The coefficient of rolling resistance for a pneumatic tire used in motor vehicles on a smooth asphalt or concrete surface is indicated in the range 0.007 to 0.02 [1-9], most often indicated around 0.012.” Using the value 0.012, a mass of 1500 kg for the car,  and 9.8 m/s$^2$ for $g$ gives a rolling resistance force 177 N. If we were able to assume that value of rolling resistance force opposes the initiation of rolling (which, as indicated earlier, may not be a correct assumption), then it would be, as you say,  the “critical rolling force”.

Comment: According to a Scientific American article on human strength, an adult male is able to apply a pushing force of 107 lbf (476 N) for a short period of time. Given that he should be able to get the car rolling with a net force of 476-177 or about 300 N. That would give the car an acceleration of  0.2 m/s$^2$ and a speed after 10 seconds of about  2 m/s.

Comment: In conclusion it would appear that rolling resistance should play a critical role in opposing the initiation of motion when the man pushes on the car, but it is not clear how to quantify the force given it is normally specified for an object already rolling.

Since we already have lengthy comments, If you wish to continue with this we should probably do it in chat. Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: @Photon It would be nice if you would at least acknowledge my attempt to address your question as I invested a considerable amount of time formulating it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I gave the answer an upvote already! I am still a bit confused how to quantify the critical force to start rolling and if it is safe to say that it is non-zero but not equal to (and lower than) the one required to start sliding. In the mean time I read that the rolling resistance coefficient $\mu_R$ actually has a dimension of length and thus $\mu_R F_N$ yields a torque rather than a force, which may be a pointer which helps answering the question but on the first glance makes things even more confusing...

Comment: @Photon Where did you read that the coefficient of rolling resistance has units of length? According to this site: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/rolling-friction-resistance-d_1303.html and this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance it is dimensionless.

Comment: I read it in a German book by W. Demtröder. Possibly what he calls $\mu_R$ is the $b$ in the wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance#Physical_formulae

Comment: Then $Nb = Fr$ is the torque he writes about.

Comment: @Photon All this is saying is the rolling resistance force, $F$, which is calculated based on a dimensionless coefficient of rolling resistance produces a torque of $Fr$ about the axle where $r$ is the radius of the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I see that, I was just thinking, that maybe the critical force in question isn't actually a critical force but a critical torque, so it not only depends on the magnitude of the force but also on the point where the force is applied. Like in the case of a billiard game, the movement of the ball depends on the position where it is hit.

Comment: @Photon it is the force that opposes the man pushing the vehicle forward, not the torque it produces. As I indicated in my answer the static friction force is responsible for the torque that enables the non drive wheel to rotate without slipping. It only has to overcome the inertia of the wheel to produce the necessary angular acceleration when the car moves forward. That force is negligible compared to the force necessary to accelerate the entire vehicle. Regardless, it still doesn't answer the question of what rolling resistance force, if any, is associated with initiating rolling.

Comment: @Photon Take a look at this article, in particular, the first equation on tractive resistance https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/rolling-resistance-coefficient

Comment: Also, check out Charles Collin's answer here; https://www.quora.com/How-much-force-is-needed-to-move-a-car He is using rolling resistance as the resistance to start rolling. He makes the interesting statement "With rolling resistance, the assumption is the vehicle is rolling so there is not a direct static rolling friction anology though since even a small amount of force will begin rolling even if very slowly,..." He adds once you get it started rolling it's easier to keep it rolling, which matches my experience. I think its coming together for me if you wish to discuss further. Bob.

Comment: Well, according to "since even a small amount of force will begin rolling even if very slowly", there is no critical force to start rolling. But this contradicts to "once you get it started rolling it's easier to keep it rolling", isn't it?

Comment: @Photon.That's the way I feel too. Clearly, once rolling, rolling resistance is the critical force that must be overcome to keep rolling (assuming low speed and negligible air drag). But if rolling resistance also resists the initiation of rolling, then rolling resistance must be greater when it opposes the initiation of rolling than after rolling occurs. Why else would it be harder to start rolling than to continue rolling? Your thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure whether my intuition that there is a critical force and the force drops a little once the body starts moving, as it happens with gliding, is actually correct. Maybe the intuition comes from everyday experience where gliding is involved somewhere on the axis? I think, you pointed this out somewhere... So I am still at the very beginning, not knowing if a critical force exists, and if it is the case, how to calculate it or at least determine if it is smaller than the critical force for gliding. Like, how does this graph, as the linked one, look for the rolling case? Still no idea!..

Answer (score 1):

Your two scenarios are categorically different and cannot be compared as you do:

- In the sliding-block scenario, static friction is replaced by kinetic friction.
- But in the rolling-wheel scenario, static friction appears *simulatenously* with rolling friction (which is more appropriately called rolling *resistance*).

The reason is that rolling won't happen without static friction. A sliding wheel that experiences kinetic friction is not rolling. By definition, rolling means that the periphery motion follows the surface (it is often term *rolling without slippin* to make this point clearer).

An ideal wheel experiences no kinetic friction or resistances of any other kind while rolling. It only experiences static friction at the contact point which is kept stationary (doesn't move during the moment of contact - if it did move, then we would have sliding, and we wouldn't call it rolling). But the wheel has inertial motion and "topples over" this stationary contact point, which lifts the contact point out of contact and places a new contact point.

So, static friction is a prerequisite, a necessacity, for rolling to take place.

Under non-ideal circumstances, we might see

- axle and bearing frictions,
- soft wheel or soft surface (rubber tire expanding and compression or sand beach deforming, which consumes energy via work done on displaced particles)
- "bulging up" of material in front of the wheel (think of driving on a sandy beach where the wheel constantly has to "lift itself out" of the hole is is digging for itself)
- a slightly deformed wheel causing non-centered normal forces introducing counteracting torques

etc. All such effects absorb energy that is removed from the kinetic energy of the motion. All these effects are gathered under one headline: **rolling resistance** or rolling friction. So, essentially, rolling friction is not a friction at all but rather a collection of all the non-ideal factors that come into play during rolling in real life. And of that reason you can't expect to fully behave just like kinetic friction, i.e. don't expect constancy nor linearity of the force, don't expect it to replace static friction etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I am still unable to answer the original question based on it. Correct me if I'm wrong, but though the static friction is still there while rolling, all the effects you described don't result in a force $\mu_S F_N$ opposing the acceleration of a rolling object. But there is some kind of effective force present, which arises from the various effects you mentioned and takes out energy from the system. And I am wondering, is there a force which acts on this object before it started moving? Can it be in a force equilibrium when a very low force is applied?

Comment: "All such effects absorb energy that is removed from the kinetic energy of the motion. All these effects are gathered under one headline: rolling resistance or rolling friction". I don't believe axle and bearing frictions have anything to do with rolling resistance.

Comment: Where by "rolling resistance" I am referring to frictional  (hysteresis) losses associated with the inelastic compression and decompression of the wheel and surface materials.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, the question is, is the critical force at which the object starts
> to move dependent on whether sliding or rolling will ensue? If it is,
> is the critical force required for initiating a rolling movement equal
> to zero? If not, how can it be calculated?

We have been discussing this in the context of what the minimum force a man must exert to initiate motion of a car by pushing on it in neutral on a flat horizontal surface. Also we ask why, in real life experience, does it usually seem harder to initiate that motion than it is to maintain that motion once it occurs?

Although we have considered the possible contribution of rolling resistance, as defined by the product of the coefficient of rolling resistance and the load on the wheel, or $f_{rr}=C_{rr}N$, it appears it is not applicable to the initiation of rolling. Rolling resistance is defined as the force that resists motion *while rolling*, as opposed to the force that resists the *initiation* of rolling motion. Testing for the coefficient of rolling resistance of tires is typically determined by a rotating"drum test". For a description and discussion of the test, see here: https://ascelibrary.org/doi/full/10.1061/%28ASCE%29TE.1943-5436.0000673

So it appears that the only external force acting on the car to oppose the  initiation of motion pushing is the static friction force that acts backwards on the wheel in response to the pushing force, and which enables the wheel to roll without slipping. Normally we consider that this force only has to overcome the rotational inertia of the wheel in order to achieve the necessary angular acceleration, on the assumption that wheel bearing friction is negligible. But John Rennie, in his answer to this post: [How much force needed to push a car on neutral?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70945/how-much-force-needed-to-push-a-car-on-neutral) suggested the reason it is harder to get a car rolling than it is to keep it rolling is "Car bearings are designed to maintain a thin film of oil when they're moving, but when the car is stationary this film collapses and the friction rises considerably."

In researching bearing friction I found his comment corroborated at this site: [https://www.linearmotiontips.com/faq-what-is-stick-slip/#:~:text=Stick%2Dslip%2C%20also%20referred%20to,transition%20from%20standstill%20to%20motion](https://www.linearmotiontips.com/faq-what-is-stick-slip/#:%7E:text=Stick%2Dslip%2C%20also%20referred%20to,transition%20from%20standstill%20to%20motion). It makes the following statement:

"With recirculating bearings, the initiation of motion draws lubrication into the contact area between the two surfaces, reducing surface-to-surface contact and causing friction forces to drop. As the speed increases, the lubricant film increases and friction is further reduced."

*In conclusion, it appears that, in addition to the tires rotational inertia, static friction between the tire and road also needs to overcome static bearing friction to initiate rolling motion. But that bearing friction drops once rotation occurs.*

With regard to quantifying the initial resistance to motion John suggests, in his above answer, placing the car on a ramp and jacking the ramp up until the car starts rolling. The force acting down on the car when it starts rolling is then $mg\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the ramp with the horizontal. That force would then approximate the threshold force opposing the initiation of motion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but all the additional effects which appear in a car are not of interest here. We can just think of a hollow cylinder which needs to be rolled. Let's say, a charged sphere is positioned in the center of this cylinder and we can push it with another charged sphere. Then there is really just the round (cylinder shaped) object, which is able to roll, positioned on some surface, and a force pushing it, that's it.

Comment: "So it appears that the only external force acting on the car to oppose the initiation of motion pushing is the static friction force that acts backwards on the wheel in response to the pushing force, and which enables the wheel to roll without slipping." But it is not necessary to achieve the critical static friction force $\mu_S F_N$ to start the rolling movement, right?

Comment: @Photon $\mu_{S}F_N$ is not the static friction force necessary to start the rolling movement. It is the maximum possible static friction force for the object to roll without sliding, i.e., for the object to undergo pure rolling. There is no minimum force necessary to initiate rolling.  The smallest push $F$ will initiate both rolling and translation, as long as $F\gt 0$ and there are no other forces opposing rotation. An example of such an opposing force is the initial static friction in the wheel bearing of my car example.

Comment: For your cylinder there is no static friction force like a dry wheel bearing opposing rotation. For the cylinder being pushed by a force $F$ (electrostatic or physical),  no matter how small as long as it is greater than zero, there will be an equal static friction force causing the cylinder to undergo pure rotation. If, however, $F=\mu_{s} mg$ the cylinder will begin to slide as well as roll.

Comment: So, how would I go about calculating the acceleration of the center of mass for such a cylinder? If the object is already moving and the external force is greater than $\mu_r F_N$, the acceleration is given by $\left(F_\text{ext}-\mu_r F_N\right)/m$, that's clear. If the object is already moving and the external force is lower than $\mu_r F_N$, the acceleration is zero, thus the velocity is constant, no matter the value of my external force, so we have $F_r = F_\text{ext}$.

Comment: If the object is not yet moving and the force is greater than $\mu_r F_N$, we have again the acceleration $\left(F_\text{ext}-\mu_r F_N\right)/m$, the object starts moving with this acceleration immediately. If the object is not yet moving and the external force is lower than $\mu_r F_N$, what happens then?

Comment: Will there be a force $F_r=F_\text{ext}$ leading to zero acceleration and thus preventing the object from starting to roll?

Comment: @Photon This getting way to involved to cover in comments. I suggest we continue in Chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141050/discussion-between-photon-and-bob-d).